# Removing first line with pattern with _both_ awk and sed

Tags: sed, awk

Fairly easy. I'm looking for the simplest approaches in both `sed` and `awk` for removing the first line in a file that contains a specific string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest solutions then are:

Sed:

```
sed -i '0,/string/{//d}' file
```

Awk:

```
awk '/string/ && !p {p++;next}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

These might work for you:

```
sed 'x;/./{x;b};x;/string/{h;d}' file
```

or

```
awk '/string/ && !p {p++;next}1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

using gnu sed:

sed '0,/MYSTRING/{//d;}' file        # delete only the first match

Comment: The termination's (`;`) not needed, is it?